# Change HTML form Using SelectionBox

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Hi and thank you for your help

i have this form :

```
    <form name="form1" action="/action_page.php">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Student information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Student Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

And this one :

```
    <form name="form2" action="/action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Prof information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Prof Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Prof classe:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

i need to show one of this form in my html page using an optionbox like this one :

```
    <select>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```

if the person shoose the first option then show the form 1 else the form 2

thank you for ur help

Comment: you can write on select option change and show correct form

Comment: HOW . can u help me with a code

Comment: i have posted complete sample below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can handle change event and make forms visible or hidden..

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
    document.querySelector('select').onchange=changeEventHandler;
},false);

function changeEventHandler(event) {
 if(event.target.value!="Prof"){
    document.getElementsByName("form2")[0].style.display="none";
    document.getElementsByName("form1")[0].style.display="block";
    }
    else { document.getElementsByName("form2")[0].style.display="block";
    document.getElementsByName("form1")[0].style.display="none"; }
    }
```

```html
<form name="form1" action="/action_page.php">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Student information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Student Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
 <form name="form2" action="/action_page.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Prof information:</legend>
    First name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Prof Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    Prof classe:<br>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
</form>
 <select>
  <option value="Student">Student</option>
  <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectForm">
    <option value="Student">Student</option>
    <option value="Prof">Prof</option>
</select>

<script>
$(document).on("change", "#selectForm", function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Student") {
        $("#form1").show();
        $("#form2").hide();
    }
    if($(this).val() == "Prof") {
        $("#form2").show();
        $("#form1").show();
    }
})
</script>
```

By default set `display:none` to both ofthe forms